# transform tuples to tree

Tags: algorithm

I have a directed acyclic graph(tree) described by (Parent1 -> Child1), (Parent2 -> Child2), ...., (ParentN -> ChildN) tuples. Is there any algorithm that reconstructs the tree(graph) from these informations?

A better example:

```
Root
  Parent1
     Node1
       Child1
       Child2
  Parent2
     Node1
       Child1
       Child2
```

and as input I have only:

```
Root -> Parent1
Node1 -> Child1
Root -> Parent2
Parent1 -> Node1
Parent2 -> Node1
Node1 -> Child2
```

in no particular order.

Having only these tuples, can we reconstruct the tree in a structure like:

Node(name:String, children:List) ?

Comment: Are `Root.Parent1.Node1` the same as `Root.Parent2.Node1`?

Comment: They're the same logically, but in the tree they should be represented as duplicate entities whose children are also dupped.

Comment: Minor nit pick: a DAG need not be a tree. It is better that you clarify which one you want to address, DAG or an undirected tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a depth-first traversal starting at the root, allowing nodes to be visited multiple times (the graph must be acyclic of course for this to terminate). For each graph node you visit, you create a corresponding tree node, and connect it to the corresponding tree node of its parent graph node (**edit:** actually, a graph node can correspond to more than one tree node, you are interested in the last).

For example, say your root is `A`:

```
    A
   / \
  /   \
 B     C
  \   /
   \ /
    D
```

You visit `A`, create `tA`. The traversal goes to B, you create `tB`, connect it to `tA`. Then you visit 'D', create `tD`, connect it to `tB`, then you backtrack and visit 'C', create `tC` and connect it to `tA`, so you get this tree:

```
    tA
   / \
  /   \
 tB   tC
 |    |
 |    |
 tD   tD'
```

Note that you may get an exponentially larger tree compared to the graph by such a transformation.

Comment: yes, this was the solution I used finally. Thank you for interest in my question and for your good response!

Comment: Glad to be of help. I said something potentially misleading (see edit) but hopefully you weren't confused.

Answer (score 3):

It was not clear to me if you were looking for pointer data structure or not. It seems what you are looking for is that at the end you should be able to list all the children of a node. If that is the requirement, what you could do is create a hash table (as per your example, from string to string). Then in your file readline loop set the parent as a key in the hash table and a vector of strings as the corresponding value. Push the child on this vector. In C++ it will look like the following

```
#include <hash_map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
hash_map<string, vector<string>* > graph;
string parent, child;
```

Then in the file readline loop

```
cin >> parent >> child >> child;
if ( graph[parent] == graph.end() ) {
    graph[parent] = new vector<string>();
}
graph[parent]->push_back(child);
```

Remember to delete the vectors once you are done, or use auto_ptr.

In pseudocode:

```
for every tuple:
    create HashTable entry with key = tuple.parent
    HashTable[tuple.parent].addToList(tuple.child)
```

Comment: I'm more interested in a pseudocode(I'm a java programmer) that constructs this tree with an optimal number of operations - perhaps from a single walk through the input tuples.

Comment: @tanderson Java has HashMap and Vector containers, so the translation to java should be easy. The solution above does walk over the input tuples only once. If you do not require random access to the different children of a node you could replace Vector by a List.

Comment: I don't think it would work as expected: to have all nodes under Parent1/Node1 and Parent2/Node1 dupped ... or am I missing something?

Comment: @tanderson For a directed graph if you have edges a->b and b->a you need both in your tuple stream. So the algo above will take care of it.